# Easy: Passing data to c program from terminal (Mac)

Tags: c, macos, parameters, terminal

So, this is a really basic question. For an assignment we had to write a c program that would calculate the page and offset number of a virtual address. My program seems to work fine when I make a vocal variable of the virtual address that we are supposed to do calculations on, but I can't figure out how to pass it.

The assignment says that we should run our program like this

```
./program_name 19982
```

I just can't figure out how to pass that 19982 in terminal on my mac. Any help is appreciated. (And in before someone makes a mac joke.)

Comment: Do you want to know, how to make your program take the number 19982 and use it, instead of creating hard-coded variable?

Comment: Yes that is exactly it. My input into terminal is 
`gcc myprog.c` to compile then
`/a.out ` to run

but i don't know where to put the 19982 in that equation. I have my main already set up to accept an argument, but I just don't know how to pass it in terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [`argv`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Program-Arguments.html), which I suppose is difficult to search for if you don't know what it is called! This isn't specific to Mac OS X's Terminal.

The `argv` argument of a `main()` function is an array of strings; its elements are the individual command line argument strings.

The path to the program being run is the first element of `argv`, that is `argv[0]`.

The number of elements in `argv` is stored in `argc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int arg;
    for (arg = 0; arg < argc; ++arg)
    {
        printf("Arg %d is %s\n", arg, argv[arg]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
% gcc program_name.c -o program_name
```

[Run](http://ideone.com/iMtB6):

```
% ./program_name 19982
Arg 0 is ./program_name
Arg 1 is 19982
```

Converting `argv[1]` to an `int` is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `argc` and `argv` to access program's arguments. `argc` is the "arguments count" - the number of arguments passed. `argv` is the "arguments vector", where the first member is the name of the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int Address;
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        Address = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("No arguments passed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Errr ... missing a string to int conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you'd use "argv/argc" in main.  For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
    printf ("You didn't enter any arguments\n");
  else
    printf ("Your first argument is %s\n", argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Under Linux, you'd compile and run like this:

```
gcc -o hello hello.c
./hello howdy!
```

Again under Linux, it would output something like this:

```
Your first argument is howdy!
```

Answer (score 1):

All C (and C++, don't know about objective-c) programs start their execution in the function `main`. This function takes two arguments: An integer, usually named `argc` which is a counter of the number of arguments given to the program; The second function argument is an array of `char` pointers, usually called `argv` and is the actual command line arguments.

The first entry in `argv` is always the name of the command itself, which means that `argc` will always be at least 1.

The following program prints all arguments given on the command line:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Total number of values in argv: %d\n", argc);
    for (int a = 0; a < argc; a++)
        printf("argv[%02d]: %s\n", a, argv[a]);
}
```